# Changing integer with setState not showing up in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, increment

Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out a solution to this problem so hopefully someone can spot what I am doing wrong here...
Essentially the component handles the Data, dynamically creating the JSX, including the quantity and a button affixed with the plusOne() function. When clicking on the plusOne() button this does in fact increase the quantity by 1, however this does not show in the render.

Any questions about my code I'll be happy to try and answer them. Thanks for reading!

```
import dummyData from './dummyData.json';



class Order extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            api: null
        };
        this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this);
        this.findDescription = this.findDescription.bind(this);
        this.minusOne = this.minusOne.bind(this);
        this.plusOne = this.plusOne.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(this.state.api)
            .then((res) => {
                this.handleData(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.handleData(false);
            })
    }
    findDescription(productIds, data) {
        var product = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
            for (let p = 0; p < data.products.length; p++) {
                if(data.products[p].id === productIds[i]) {
                    product.push(data.products[p]);
                }
            }
        }
        return product;
    }
    handleData(data) {
        if(!data) {
            data = dummyData;
        }
        console.log(data);
        let orderId = this.props.match.params.id;
        let grandTotal = data.orders[orderId-1].total;
        let item = data.orders[orderId-1].items;
        let productIds = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            productIds.push(item[i]['product-id']);
        }
        let product = this.findDescription(productIds, data);
        let singleOrderItems = [];
        this.setState({
            product,
            item
        }, () => {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.item.length; i++) {
                singleOrderItems.push(
                    <div key={i} className="single-order-container">
                        <ul>
                            <li>{this.state.product[i].description}</li>
                            <li>Quantity: {this.state.item[i].quantity}</li>
                            <li>Price per Item: {this.state.item[i]["unit-price"]}</li>
                            <li>Total: {this.state.item[i].total}</li>
                            <button onClick={this.minusOne(i)} name="minus">-</button>
                            <button onClick={this.plusOne(i)} name="plus">+</button>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })
        this.setState({
            singleOrderItems,
            grandTotal
        })
    }
    minusOne(i) {
        var self = this;
        return function() {
            console.log(self.state.item);
        }
    }
    plusOne(i) {
        var self = this;
        return function() {
            let quantity = self.state.item[i].quantity ++;
            self.setState({
                quantity
            });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>Order {this.props.match.params.id} </div>
                {this.state.singleOrderItems}
                <div>Grand Total: {this.state.grandTotal}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Order
```

Answer (score 0):

The state does indeed change, the content just doesn't render with the correct state because the original creation of the Components array happens in the promise within your componentDidMount.

Perhaps you could store your response data in your state and create the content on render (or another lifecycle method)